# Fast method to locate occurrences of SQL queries via code?

Tags: 8, database

I'm reviewing some SQL queries made throughout a few modules, but to do that, I've been reading every line of code manually, which is time consuming.

Is there a term or phrase I could CTRL+F for to find out where the queries are occurring directly? Any packages I should be on the look for?

Comment: look for the execute() method of load()/loadMultiple() in case of entities for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try CTRL+F-ing for these:

1. `db_query`
2. `->query(`
3. `\Drupal\Core\Database\Connection::query()`
4. `\Drupal\Core\Database\Connection::defaultOptions()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Webprofiler](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module (part of [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)).

Enable the module and check the saved profiles by the [Webprofiler](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module via `/admin/reports/profiler/list`. Select the `Database` option on the left and you should see the executed queries.